# Not able to create app for plaltform facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I have a app ( web, ios and android ).I want to the create a Facebook canvas app where it will only show the first page of our web app.To achieve this.I created a Facebook canvas app in Facebook developer console.I filled the details which was required (Secure Canvas URL : https://example.com ,Mobile Site URL : https://example.com ) I am not sure what is secure canvas url meant so I put the link of my web app.But when open the canvas page 
( https://apps.facebook.com/some_id).It is giving 405 Not allowed error.After digging I found out that Facebook is making a post request to my web app with a signed request ( not sure what it is ). How do I show my web page on facebook canvas page.Please explained to me how this things works and how can I achieve it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating a canvas app that just displays the first page of your web app?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook loads app into the iframe by making a POST request to your app URL. You typically get a `405 Not allowed` when your URL does not accept POST requests.

Many webspace providers have a setup where POST requests to “static” resources (such as `.htm`/`.html` files) are not allowed.

So you need to either change that in the webserver configuration (might be possible via .htaccess on an Apache; ask your server admin/support if you’re not sure), or you need to use a different “file type” for your app’s base URL that you want to load into canvas - for example, if PHP is available, the configuration usually allows POST requests to PHP scripts by default.

Comment: what is Secure Canvas URL and signed_request which is send along with POST request.

Comment: Secure Canvas URL is the HTTPS URL of where you host your app. And the signed_request is a parameter send along on the additional load of the app into the iframe, containing some additional information.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request

Comment: @CBroe, hey, my server is built on Django, and I am processng the POST request to render a static html page. When I make the request from `Postman REST Client`, the web page is rendered whereas in Canvas all I get is a blank page. Even inspecting that shows empty

Comment: Your URL is a HTTPS one, and you do have a valid SSL certificate for it?

Comment: yes, the URL is HTTPS, but no apart from that, there isn't anything else

Comment: So can you visit the URL directly in your browser, without any warnings regarding HTTPS/the certificate?